# How to add bottom shadow to table cell with dynamic height?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uitableview, calayer

I am about to implement bottom shadow for table cells. However my table cells have dynamic heights and each cell can be toggled to expand or shrink. I would like to have the bottom shadow anchored to the bottom of each cell.

My question is, if I generate the shadow using BPath in CALayer, how can I anchor the layer to the bottom of a view?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS 3.2 or later, you can use the shadow-specific properties in CALayer - `shadowColor`, `shadowOffset`, `shadowOpacity`, `shadowPath` and `shadowRadius`.

```
[cell.layer setShadowOpacity:0.4];
```

You will have to manually adjust the shadow layer pre-iOS 3.2 and there is no automatic way in iOS to anchor it to the bottom. What you were looking for was `CAConstraintLayoutManager` which is available in OSX but not in iOS.